# Can I put a Doctype in the middle of the code?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, doctype, quirks-mode

Hi this is my first time here, so thanks for any help/advice you can give!

I started work somewhere that has a CMS and as such we work by templates. But these templates don't have Doctypes delcared at the top (And we're not allowed to change that :( ) and so it throws anything we develop into Quirks mode when it's viewed in IE. It means front-end coding is "very" difficult to cope with.

So my question is, can I cheat somehow and put in a Doctype halfway through a document? Would iframing it in help? How can I make my code look at least similar in each browser?

I know the best solution is to get a Doctype at the top of the document. But I don't have control of that, as of yet.

Any advice is appreciated! :)

Comment: "But these templates don't have Doctypes delcared at the top (And we're not allowed to change that" — It's been best practise to trigger standards mode for new development since IE6 come out in 2001. You need to fix your company culture to get it out of the last century.

Answer (score 0):

The `<!DOCTYPE html>` decoration must be at the top of any page and cannot be within `<html>` tag.

Please see the article. http://www.w3.org/wiki/Doctypes_and_markup_styles. It should be declared somewhere, like in a head file or some such.

Edit: Format + Added up to date relevant documentation.